# Show desktop 2's on HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a laptop I'd like to split in two desktops: one on the on laptop's screen, and the other on a HDMI screen. Is this possible? If it is possible, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look up at your laptol manual, you need a grapchic card/chipset that supports simultaneous displays. If not, HDMI is only intended for duplicate or external display.